# Grep strings containing two or more words

Tags: bash, shell

I have three strings

```
strA="a b mam am"
strB="a b a"
strC="a b a c"
```

and I want to grep strings containing two or more words "a", so `strA` shouldn't return anything, while `strB` and `strC` should.

I tried this command: `echo "a b a" | grep  "a *a"` but why isn't it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because " `*`" matches zero or more spaces, but nothing else. The regex for "anything" is `.*` (the dot matches any character and the star allows for zero or more repetitions). However, that would match `mam am` whereas you apparently want word matches, so try

```
grep '\<a\>.*\<a\>'
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `grep` support `-P` option you can try something like

```
$ echo "a b a" | grep -P "\ba\b.*\ba\b"
a b a
```

- `\b` matches word boundaries
- `\ba\b` matches `words "a"`

Answer (score 1):

Grep can take more complex regular expressions:

```
grep -E "\ba\b.*\ba\b"
```

Breakdown:

- `\b` - Word Boundary
- `a` - The word
- `\b` - Word Boundary
- `.*` - Zero or more characters
- `\b` - Word Boundary
- `a` - The word
- `\b` - Word Boundary

The `\b` marks the end of *word boundaries* and will whether the word is at the beginning of the line, the middle or the end. Whether it is surrounded by spaces, tabs, or has a punctuation character around it.

You could use `\+` instead of `\*` because you're still specifying a word boundary, so either one will catch `a a`.

Note I use `-E` as a parameter in `grep`. This ensures that more complex regular expressions are used. In Gnu `grep`, this makes no difference, but does on BSD platforms like Mac OS X.